# URLs with several path components get sent directly to static file handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have the following problem with an Asp.net MVC application when running on IIS (tested with version 7.0 and 8.5) : if the path in the URL has no more than 3 components (for example http://myhost.com/a/b/c, it gets correctly handled by the application code. But when an additional component is added in the path (http://myhost.com/a/b/c/d), it will be sent directly to the static file handler. As the path is not used for a physical file, I get a 404 (with the error page coming from the static file handler, not the custon 404 page configured in `web.config`)

I don't have this problem on my dev station running IIS Express.

I use `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in web.config, disabling it doesn't solve the issue.

Disabling the static file handler doesn't help, I still get a 404 but this time the error message says "Handler **Not yet determined**".

I really looks this is something happening very early in IIS processing, because if I recycle the application pool and try to access to this URL, the response comes immediately, without the usual delay that I get when the application needs to start.

What am I missing? Why is IIS not forwarding such requests to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something: the long url was not handled by an MVC route, but by an OWIN middleware. Somehow, it seems that for IIS, if no route is configured for an URL, then the request pipeline is completely ignored, including any OWIN middlewares (and also custom page for 404).

By adding another parameter in a route like suggested by heymega, I was able to work around the problem, the OWIN middlewares were executed. I added the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute("CatchLongUrls", "{a}/{b}/{c}/{*d}", 
    new {controller = "Invalid", action = "Nothing"});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your routes!!

The default route in MVC only takes over controller, action & ID. You're trying to use a fourth which you haven't defined. Just add another url parameter to your route collection.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{another}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, another= UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not, that's not the problem, my routes are configured correctly. And if that was the problem, I would see it in IIS Express as well, but it works there.

Comment: Actually, this works around the problem, but without solving the root cause. See my more detailed answer.